# Why I get undefined when using fileTypeFromBuffer?

Tags: node.js, express

I send an image to my express server and want to use fileTypeFromBuffer but I got undefined. What I am doing wrong ? I am very new to chunks and buffer.

```
  let data = [];
  req.on("data", (chunk) => {
    // collect incoming stream chunks in an array
    data.push(chunk);
  });

  req.on("end", async ()=>{
    let fileData = Buffer.concat(data);

    const fileType = await FileType.fileTypeFromBuffer(fileData);

    console.log(fileType );

  
  });
```